# How to resoleve Exception: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future?

Tags: ros, transforms, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was publishing a frame using launch file.

I was getting below errors.
tf2.waitForTransform(src_fram, des_frame, rospy.get_rostime(), rospy.Duration(10.0));
Exception: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1468340743.794792891 but the latest data is at time 2117.120000000, when looking up transform from frame [bed_frame] to frame [wide_stereo_optical_frame]. canTransform returned after 10.0004 timeout was 10.

I have used all time combinations such as rspy.Time(), rospy.get_rostime(), and rospy.Time.now(). but no luck.
i also used sleep function for 10 seconds before waitForTransform, this is also not worked

here is my code

```
def getTransformedPoint(faceCoordinate, src_fram, des_frame):
point = PointStamped()
point.point.x = faceCoordinate[0];
point.point.y = faceCoordinate[1];
point.point.z = faceCoordinate[2];
point.header.frame_id = src_fram;
point.header.stamp = rospy.Time();
print "rospy.Time(): ",point.header.stamp;
print "rospy.get_rostime(): ",rospy.get_rostime();
print "rospy.Time.now(): ", rospy.Time.now();

tf2.waitForTransform(src_fram, des_frame, rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(10.0));

desired_frame = tf2.transformPoint(des_frame, point)
print desired_frame
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239346/how-to-resoleve-exception:-lookup-would-require-extrapolation-into-the-future?/) by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The above code is working after setting simulation time to true in the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [anilmullapudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26823/anilmullapudi/) with karma: 75 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0